# how to shuffle data of a column in sql?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Is it possible to shuffle data of a column in sqlite android?
I have two columns from which I want to shuffle `alph` in sqlite on a `click event` in android

```
num     alph
------------
 1       a
 2       b
 3       c
 4       d
```

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SQLiteDatabase db;
String a,c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("dat", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rk(num integer,alph char);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('1','a');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('2','b');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('3','c');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('4','d');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('5','e');");
}
public void disp(View view){
    EditText ed;
    ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    a=ed.getText().toString();
    Cursor  b=db.rawQuery("SELECT alph FROM rk WHERE num='a';",null);
    //System.out.println(b.getString(0));

    c=b.toString();
    System.out.println("a2");
    System.out.println(c);
    Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(c);
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by shuffling `alph` ? if you want to display `alph` data shuffled at the view then you should do it at the view layer not the database layer.

Comment: i want the data in db to be altered...

Answer (score 1):

do you mean get a random row out of that ? in MySQL you would accomplish that by:

```
select alph from rk order by rand() limit 0,1
```

I would think this sql would work in SQLite as well in same or similar form. If you want all rows in random order, just remove the "limit 0, 1" part like:

```
select alph from rk order by rand()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from tablename order by random()` // remember rand() is not there for sqllite use random instead